# Make gcc default c compiler on Yosemite/disable clang

Tags: c, bash, gcc, osx-yosemite

I recently updgraded to Mac Yosemite and as usual there are some growing pains.  The first one seems to be the default C compiler.

I am compiling some code in bash with an external tool that uses gcc, however it needs to compile some other code (that I did not write).  For some reason, clang is being used to compile this code, but I'd prefer to use gcc.  My guess as to why is that clang has been set as the default compiler and the compiling code is using the default compiler for its sub-compilation.  Is there a way to force gcc to be the default C compiler on Yosemite.  I tried looking around but everything I've seen so far was in terms of making it the default in Xcode tools, rather than on bash.

Comment: You might configure and compile and install a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) (e.g. 4.9.1) from its source code.

Comment: are you able to explicitly execute gcc in bash by just typing 'gcc'? If that's the case, you could try putting 'export CC=gcc' into your ~/.bashrc

Comment: I've done this and it still uses clang in the at some point even after doing that.  From that I'm running into the unknown flags issue with clang, which I've been trying to fix using all the known fixes, but none seem to work.