# Set cc to gcc instead of clang on OSX Yosemite

Tags: c, macos, gcc, clang, osx-yosemite

I've been trying to get Mac OSX Yosemite to use gcc instead of clang when cc is invoked, but no matter what I do, it refuses to play along.  I've already tried changing my bash_profile/bashrc and even relinking the symlink, but to no avail--every time I invoke "cc" it is still clang that runs.  I'm trying to force it to be gcc instead (and no, just calling gcc is not an option).

I previously asked a similar question ([Make gcc default c compiler on Yosemite/disable clang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26470284/make-gcc-default-c-compiler-on-yosemite-disable-clang)).

Comment: I'm always interested when people say they want to use gcc over clang - do you have ideological reasons or some other goal in mind?

Comment: No,I just need to run a very arcane piece of software that assumes gcc but cannot run with clang.

Comment: In XCode 6, the `gcc` is a link to `clang`, not the genuine `gcc`.  You'd have to get a custom build of GCC in some shape or form, and then change the links (and risk having them changed if you upgrade XCode and install the command line tools again).

Comment: i suppose that firstly you should make sure it's real `gcc`, not a wrapper for `clang`; and then make sure that the *real* `gcc` is firstly found in `$PATH`, you can `export CC=/path/to/real/gcc` if you prefer. Note that some setup scripts might specify CC during `configure`, but others are allowed to change during `make`; read the build help if there are.

Answer (score 12):

Neither OS X nor Xcode comes with real GCC. For compatibility with scripts which assume the compiler is called "gcc", it has executables by that name, but they are all fronts for Clang. No amount of symlinking, setting environment variables, or setting up aliases will allow those executables to run real GCC.

If you want GCC, you need to install it. You can do that using one of the package managers, such as MacPorts (the one I'm familiar with). I'm sure you could also use Homebrew.

You should not modify anything in /usr/bin. If you've already done so, you should restore what you've changed, if possible.

Well-behaved package managers will also not modify that directory. They should install to a separate directory such as /opt/local/bin, /usr/local/bin, or the like. In that case, you will want to modify your `PATH` to put those directories earlier than /usr/bin.

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't do this. A lot of tools rely on the installation binaries to point to what they should. Another option is to set the environment variable `CC` to `gcc`, and invoke compilation with `$CC ...` rather than `cc ...` ; this environment variable will also be picked up when building packages via `configure` (autotools) or `cmake`.

This is also a compatible approach with MacPorts versions of gcc (like the much more up to date gcc-4.9.2), which can be set up with: `sudo port select --set gcc mp-gcc49`

Comment: I tried setting environment variables and it didn't work.  This is also not a case where I'm calling cc or gcc manually, or have any real control over which is called, so instead that's why I'm trying to get cc to just run gcc.

Comment: @Hendrik - I suppose you could try setting up an alias, e.g., `alias cc="gcc"` (bash) or `alias cc 'gcc'` ([t]csh). But this is also [problematic](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1496/why-doesnt-my-bash-script-recognize-aliases).

Comment: Does the software at least respect `PATH`?  You could try giving it an environment which only knows about gcc (and not clang)

Comment: @BrettHale `gcc` on OS X actually calls Calng too (trying `gcc -v` returns `clang-700.1.81` - the same as when trying `cc -v`...)

Comment: @AvielGross - you'll notice it is also configured with `gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1` - that is, an old g++ std library. With no C++11 support. It's for maintaining apps, etc., built during Apple's gcc / clang transition. You don't want this for any modern development.